# window in new tab at mvc with javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

```
window.location = '@Url.Action("PrintReport", "Report")?from=' + $("#fromDate").val() + '&to=' + $("#toDate").val();
```

How could i open it at new tab?
I call it in JavaScript against a click.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on WHAT you click have

```
var url = '@Url.Action("PrintReport", "Report")?from=' + 
          $("#fromDate").val() + '&to=' + $("#toDate").val();

window.open(url,"_blank")
```

or better: have a link with target="_blank" -

```
  <a href="#" target="_blank" 
  onclick="this.href='@Url.Action("PrintReport", "Report")?from=' +
  $("#fromDate").val() + '&to=' + $("#toDate").val();">Print</a>
```

Or unobtrusive:

```
  <a href="#" id="printReport" target="_blank" >Print</a>
```

using

```
$(function() {
  $("#printReport").on("click",function(e) {
    $(this).attr("href",'@Url.Action("PrintReport", "Report")?from=' +
    $("#fromDate").val() + '&to=' + $("#toDate").val());
  });
});
```

or both:

```
$(function() {
  $("#printReport").on("click",function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    window.open('@Url.Action("PrintReport", "Report")?from=' +
    $("#fromDate").val() + '&to=' + $("#toDate").val(),"_blank");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    var id = $('#hdnQuickSalesOrderId').val().trim();

    var url = '@Url.Action("OrderDetailDashboard", "Order", new { orderValue = "__id" })';
    var New =  url.replace("__id", id)
    window.open(New);
```